# Why does Itoshiki-sensei always wear a kimono?

Tags: sayonara-zetsubou-sensei

Itoshiki-sensei is always seen wearing a kimono whereever he is, except in episode six when he is in his hometown, wearing a shirt, but after that he change his clothes to a kimono again.

[image: Itoshiki in a kimono]
[image: Itoshiki in a shirt]

Answer (score 2):

The show uses a lot of traditional Japanese cultural imagery, including the characters' clothes. Wikipedia says the style is supposed to be taken from Showa period (most probably [1926~1989](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dwa_period) years, less likely [1312~1317](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sh%C5%8Dwa_%28Kamakura_period%29)).

It's a comedy and satire show, so naturally, the main protagonist would wear something noticeable as a traditional kimono. But because characters are usually seen in modern environment, things like this keep us from forgetting the older-timey setting.

Comment: `The Shōwa period (昭和時代 Shōwa jidai?, potentially "period of enlightened peace/harmony" or "period of radiant Japan"), or Shōwa era, is the period of Japanese history corresponding to the reign of the Shōwa Emperor, Hirohito, from December 25, 1926, through January 7, 1989.[1]` Don't know how you got the 1300s...

Comment: I cite the first paragraph from Wikipedia in my comment.

Comment: lol Willipedia?

Answer (score 1):

There's one episode (can't recall the number off of my head) where Itoshiki-Sensei exclaims that he's a "Bona-fide Japanese" (in one of the subbed translations I was watching) and it's possible he's not really fond of westernized shirts/clothes that much.

Comment: But he does wear them at home. Gotta be a reason why.